# how to call a get web service from javascript when the data returned by web changes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call a web-service with in javascript and get the data from web-service.

I want to trigger the ajax call again when the data returned by web services changes.

Here is code i tried with, but failed to trigger callback again when data from server changes.

```
var request=$.get("http://localhost:8080/messanger/webresources/myresource",function(data){
            if(data=="something"){
                //do something
            }
            else if(data=="something else"){
               //do something else
            }
        });
```

When the data from web-services changes, i want to execute the get request again!!!

Please suggest the concept to do this...

Comment: You mean call the api again in else if method?

Comment: @Martin I need to call the api again if data returned by web-service differs from previous call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest recursive call of function that calls the service. It is beeing called just as long as the result differs from the previous one. But im still not sure if it is what zou want:)

```
var previousResult = null;

function callMyService() {
    var request = $.get("http://localhost:8080/messanger/webresources/myresource", function (data) {
        if (data == previousResult) {
            // returned data is the same as last call
        }
        else {
            // save the previous result to global variable
            previousResult = data;
            // recursive call
            callMyService();            
        }
    });
}
```

Then call is wherever you need to:

```
callMyService()
```